# Extending HTML5 mobile app for more file storage

Tags: html, cordova, mobile-website, dropbox-api

My team is writing an HTML5 app that uses the appcache and localstorage heavily. Our target platform is ipad and android tablets (and design time we work extensively in desktop browsers, though that's not necessarily a must-have).

Now we want to add some offline-available features that will be beyond what the browser-based storage can support-- namely a library of video & binary content that will be bigger than the appcache can handle.

Without the major mobile browsers implementing the html5 filesystem api, it seems very much like some kind of native app approach will be required (PLEASE correct me if I'm wrong here... I'd love to be wrong on this!). So, I'd love to hear opinions/experiences folks have had. We're noodling around with a few different ideas involving one or more of the following:

1. Compiling in phonegap + using their file apis
2. Using the Dropbox sdk (which would also require some kind of native support, not sure if phonegap would work)
3. writing per-platform custom native apps that host webkit controls, then providing the majority of functionality with our existing, cross-platform html5 app (basically we'd be writing a per-platform custom browser using the standard webkit controls).

Note that I'm a fan of #3 because I feel like we could release a relatively stable shell but then preserve the html5 cross-platform goodness & ease of distribution of our app. However, I don't know if this approach works (and/or if Apple frowns upon this type of approach-- seems like a bit of an App Store loophole).

Very interested to hear what you've tried and/or heard about.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a completely stupid idea but, if you're looking for a cheap way to get extra storage, why not just use an html or js file to contain the data? You could even, for whatever reason, store it as a 64-bit data uri and run the media natively. I think you could even save data to it by just manipulating the manifest to be reflective. It'd take a bit of tom foolery, but it should work.

Comment: My understanding is that the appcache has a pretty low per-site size limit (5mb or thereabouts but different per browser)  A few megs is fine for our app itself, but small potatoes if we want to support a content library of video clips, photos, etc.

Comment: I knew there was a limit of roughly 5mb for the appcache/localstorage, but I was not aware that the limit was applied to the actual source code.

Comment: There's a 50Mb limit on iOS, but caching video is flaky and files can become easily corrupted so not a good idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If you use approach 1 you will be well positioned to move to a web app once the major browsers support the File API. You see the File API in PhoneGap is based on the W3C spec that the browsers will implement.

2, I started working on a Dropbox plugin for PhoneGap Android but I need some "spare time" to finish it.

3, Apple will probably reject your app if it is just a wrapper around your web site. They've done that in the past.

Simon